Connecting to Oracle 11g Database from Dockerized Spring Boot Application
I have created a spring boot application that connects to an external Oracle server residing separately and it works perfectly from my machine when I run the App from IntelliJ.
I have now created a Docker image of my same app. I tried to run it from my Docker hosted on Windows 11 machine but failed. Here is my application.yml

        spring:
          application:
            name: "myapp"
          datasource:
            url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.4.14:1521:orcl
            username: username
            password: password
            driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

I also tried an Oracle DB on my local machine using this url:
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//host.docker.internal:1521/orcl
But that also didn't connect from Docker.
My Oracle server 11gR2
Is there an issue/bug in connecting to Oracle from within Docker? And how to resolve that?
The key error is this (Not Dialect which can be ignored)
2024-12-09 18:05:44 2024-12-09T18:05:44.963Z  INFO 1 --- [gl] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-12-09 18:05:46 2024-12-09T18:05:46.250Z  WARN 1 --- [gl] [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
2024-12-09 18:05:46 
2024-12-09 18:05:46 java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(java.sql.SQLException, String)" because the return value of "org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.sqlExceptionHelper()" is null
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:116) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]

Here is the Log:
2024-12-09 18:05:41 
2024-12-09 18:05:41   .   ____          _            __ _ _
2024-12-09 18:05:41  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
2024-12-09 18:05:41 ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
2024-12-09 18:05:41  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
2024-12-09 18:05:41   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
2024-12-09 18:05:41  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
2024-12-09 18:05:41 
2024-12-09 18:05:41  :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.3.2)
2024-12-09 18:05:41 
2024-12-09 18:05:41 2024-12-09T18:05:41.272Z  INFO 1 --- [gl] [           main] com.myapp.one.MyApplication                : Starting MyApplication using Java 21.0.5 with PID 1 (/app/classes started by root in /)
2024-12-09 18:05:41 2024-12-09T18:05:41.275Z  INFO 1 --- [gl] [           main] com.myapp.one.MyApplication                : The following 1 profile is active: "prod"
2024-12-09 18:05:43 2024-12-09T18:05:43.892Z  INFO 1 --- [gl] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-12-09 18:05:43 2024-12-09T18:05:43.893Z  INFO 1 --- [gl] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.26]
2024-12-09 18:05:43 2024-12-09T18:05:43.967Z  INFO 1 --- [gl] [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-12-09 18:05:44 2024-12-09T18:05:44.499Z  INFO 1 --- [gl] [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2024-12-09 18:05:44 2024-12-09T18:05:44.558Z  INFO 1 --- [gl] [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.5.2.Final
2024-12-09 18:05:44 2024-12-09T18:05:44.605Z  INFO 1 --- [gl] [           main] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
2024-12-09 18:05:44 2024-12-09T18:05:44.963Z  INFO 1 --- [gl] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-12-09 18:05:46 2024-12-09T18:05:46.250Z  WARN 1 --- [gl] [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
2024-12-09 18:05:46 
2024-12-09 18:05:46 java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(java.sql.SQLException, String)" because the return value of "org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.sqlExceptionHelper()" is null
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:116) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentUsingJdbcMetadata(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:290) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:130) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:238) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:215) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:221) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:171) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1431) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1502) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1802) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:954) ~[spring-context-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625) ~[spring-context-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at com.myapp.one.MyApplication.main(MyApplication.java:44) ~[classes/:na]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 
2024-12-09 18:05:46 2024-12-09T18:05:46.264Z ERROR 1 --- [gl] [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url' for common cases or 'hibernate.dialect' when a custom Dialect implementation must be provided)
2024-12-09 18:05:46 2024-12-09T18:05:46.282Z  INFO 1 --- [gl] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 2024-12-09T18:05:46.398Z ERROR 1 --- [gl] [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
2024-12-09 18:05:46 
2024-12-09 18:05:46 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url' for common cases or 'hibernate.dialect' when a custom Dialect implementation must be provided)
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1806) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:954) ~[spring-context-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625) ~[spring-context-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at com.myapp.one.MyApplication.main(MyApplication.java:44) ~[classes/:na]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url' for common cases or 'hibernate.dialect' when a custom Dialect implementation must be provided)
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:276) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:238) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:215) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:221) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:171) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1431) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1502) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1802) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 ... 15 common frames omitted
2024-12-09 18:05:46 Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url' for common cases or 'hibernate.dialect' when a custom Dialect implementation must be provided)
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:191) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentWithDefaults(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentUsingJdbcMetadata(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:362) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:130) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
2024-12-09 18:05:46 ... 30 common frames omitted
2024-12-09 18:05:46 


Apparently ojdbc8, that I was using, is not compatible with Oracle 11g. I switched to ojdbc6 and it started working.
ojdbc8 (and for that matter even ojdbc17 also) work in development environment, from within IntelliJ, but fails in Docker.

Please update your question with the exact error message.
For network troubleshooting you can fire up a container with netcat and try something like this. I have an Oracle Database running on my MacOS.
docker run --rm --network="host" -t python:alpine nc -vz host.docker.internal 1521
host.docker.internal (192.168.65.254:1521) open
docker run --rm --network="bridge" -t python:alpine nc -vz host.docker.internal 1521
host.docker.internal (192.168.65.254:1521) open

You can try
 docker run --rm --network="bridge" -t python:alpine nc -vz external-ip 1521

This has to work before you application can connect. Probably some docker network setting og host OS setting you need to look into. Windows firewall or similar.
Update:
If netcat says 'open', you have only proved that the database listener is listening on port 1521. In order to prove that the database actually is available and that you can login with your credentials, you can fire up sqlplus from within your docker network.
cat ~/.my_oracle_password | docker login container-registry.oracle.com --username oracle.sso@email.login --password-stdin
docker run -ti --rm container-registry.oracle.com/database/instantclient sqlplus user/pass@external-ip:1521/ORCL

Best of luck!

I run this
docker run --rm --network="bridge" -t python:alpine nc -vz host.docker.internal 1521
And got this response
host.docker.internal (192.168.65.254:1521) open
Also similar response for 10.10.4.14

I have updated my answer, looks like you cannot login to the database hence the dialect error message. But there are several possible reasons why you are having this error.

I installed Oracle insantclient container-registry.oracle.com/database/instantclient
And I was able to run SQLPlus from Docker and connect to my local DB from within Docker using this command docker run -ti --rm container-registry.oracle.com/database/instantclient sqlplus MYUSERID/MyPassword@host.docker.internal:1521/ORCL . I also confirmed that data modified in my local DB is reflecting in the above sqlplus session
